# Does Chess Stack Exchange include chess-variant questions?

Tags: discussion, site-scope

I wonder, does Chess Stack Exchange include chess-variant questions? I know that there are a lot of variants of chess, like Chess960, Bughouse, Atomic, etc.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Personally, I think it should.
It's not called a CHESS-variant for nothing, and if chess.SE is not appropriate for it, then where should these questions be asked?

Comment: +1, I think that chess variants are increasingly interesting the stronger computers get as well.

Comment: Is something like Arimaa also on topic?

Comment: @linker: I don't see why not

Comment: "then where should these questions be asked?" there is always [boardgames.se]

Answer (score 12):

I would think it's ok only as long as they are properly tagged.  That way, those who are not interested in those variants can filter them out according to the tags.